# table-per-type inheritance in WCF Data service

Tags: wcf-data-services, table-per-type

I use C# Language of Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional for my Project and I have problem.

I have two Solutions.
The first Solution there is Web Project Template and it contains :
1-ADO.NET Entity Data Model for database and I used Table-per-Type inheritance in the ADO.NET Entity Data Model
2-WCF Data Service for this Entity Data Model

The second Solution there is WPF Project Template and it contains :
1-Service Reference for the WCF Data Service that exists in the first project

The problem is :

I can Not interact with any type of the base or derived Entities using the code that generated by service reference

For instance I have abstract Entity called "Person"
and two non-abstract entities derived from it "Customer" and "Employee"

When creating new customer object -or Employee object- and then add it to the context,
the SaveChanges Method throw an exception DataServiceRequestException

and I tried to use OfType() Method and I get another Exception "NotSupportedException"

What is the solution for this problem ?
Thank in advance